# Change tab header color in PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I am using PySimpleGUI to build a tab group. On certain events I want to color the "header" of a single tab with a specific background color to alert the user that something is going on in that tab. How do I achieve this?

Barebones code:

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

tabgroup_layout = [[sg.Tab("tab", [[sg.Text("something something")]], key="-TAB-")]]

mainwindow_layout = [[sg.TabGroup(tabgroup_layout, key="-TABGROUP-")],
                     [sg.Button("TEST", key="-TEST-"), sg.Button("Close", key="-CLOSE-")]]

window = sg.Window("Window", mainwindow_layout, finalize=True)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    
    if event == "-CLOSE-":
        break
    
    elif event == "-TEST-":
        # set tab color
        ...

window.close()
```

After some poking around in the attributes of the tab object, I've tried `window["-TAB-"].BackgroundColor = "#..."` and `window["-TAB-"].widget.configure(background="#...")`, both of which seem to do nothing.

I'd also settle for changing the text color in the header, but I have no idea how to achieve that either.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that you cannot set the color for specific TAB, but for all the TABs.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

tabgroup_layout = [
    [sg.Tab("Tab 1", [[sg.Text("This is the tab 1")]], key="-TAB1-"),
     sg.Tab("Tab 2", [[sg.Text("This is the tab 2")]], key="-TAB2-")]
    ]

mainwindow_layout = [[sg.TabGroup(tabgroup_layout, key="-TABGROUP-")],
                     [sg.Button("TEST", key="-TEST-"), sg.Button("Close", key="-CLOSE-")]]

window = sg.Window("Window", mainwindow_layout, finalize=True)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()

    if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, "-CLOSE-"):
        break
    elif event == "-TEST-":
        tabgroup = window['-TABGROUP-']
        style, style_name = tabgroup.Style, tabgroup.StyleName + '.Tab'
        style.map(style_name, background=[("selected", "blue")])
        # style.map(style_name, foreground=[("selected", foreground)])
        # style.configure(style_name, background=background, foreground=foreground, focuscolor=focuscolor)

window.close()
```

Comment: Hmm bummer. But thanks for the code, I'll play around with it.